# Built in functions for sorting arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting, built-in

Are there any built in functions in C programming language for sorting arrays? Or do I have to write my own functions?

Comment: `qsort` in `stdlib.h`

Comment: @nhahtdh don't post it as answer?

Comment: @triclosan: Writing 1 liner comment takes less effort than writing a full-fledged answer.

Comment: Unrelated, but `bsearch(3)` is another libc routine in the same vein as `qsort(3)` that many people do not know about. (Often, they are used together: you need to sort your array before binary searching it. =))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out qsort

Syntax:

`#include <stdlib.h>

    void qsort( void *buf, size_t num, size_t size, int (*compare)(const void *, const void *) );`

Description:

The `qsort()` function sorts buf (which contains num items, each of size size) using Quicksort. The compare function is used to compare the items in buf. compare should return negative if the first argument is less than the second, zero if they are equal, and positive if the first argument is greater than the second. qsort() sorts buf in ascending order.

Comment: NOTE: qsort() is not necessarily quicksort. (often it is, though)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/) in `stdlib.h`. <s>It is quick-sort algorithm, which has average time complexity of O(nlogn) and worst case complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>).</s> The [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) and even the newer [C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) doesn't mandate the implementation or time complexity of the function. However, it is very likely that common implementation will use algorithm that yields average case O(nlogn) time complexity (which is optimal for sorting by comparison).

You can use this to sort any kind of array (even `struct`) - but you must provide a comparison function to compare between 2 elements of the array.

Comment: NOTE: qsort() is not necessarily quicksort. (often it is, though)

Comment: You can link to the [C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) nowadays :)

Answer (score 6):

[qsort](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/qsort/) is well known. There are others also like heapsort, mergesort etc. Please check the link for more details.

Please note that all of them take comparison functions as input, making them easily usable with native as well as user created data types.

Comment: I was curious in what standard library exist `mergesort` and `heapsort`... turns out they're in FreeBSD's libc. Cool. +1 (Note: they do not appear to exist in glibc.)

Comment: They are non-standard C functions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: [`qsort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html). It's in `stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 3):

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <stdlib.h> 

  // This function is used in qsort to decide the relative order 
  // of elements at addresses p and q. 
  int comparator(const void *p, const void *q) 
   { 
      return (*(int*)p-*(int*)q);
      } 

  // A utility function to print an array 
  void printArr(int arr[], int n) 
  { 
     int i; 
     for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
     printf("%d ", arr[i]); 
  }  

  // Driver program to test above function 
  int main() 
  { 
     int arr[] = {1, 6, 5, 2, 3, 9, 4, 7, 8, 0}; 
     int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
     qsort((void*)arr, size, sizeof(arr[0]), comparator); 
     printf("Output array is\n"); 
     printArr(arr, size);  
     return 0; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple syntax :**

```
int function (const void * a, const void * b) {return ( *(int*)a-(int*)b);}
`qsort(arr_name , sizeofarray , sizeof(int), function);
```